# Can a low-bitrate BluRay video be written to DVD-R to be played by BD-players?

Tags: dvd, bluray

Assume a BD-Video directory structure with a 1080p video. It is so boring, that its max datarate is below 10MBit/s, and the entire directory structure takes less than 4.7GB.

**Instead of writing this to a BD-R, could it also be written to a DVD-R, and would BD-players run it?**

- On the one side, the data rate is lower than the max DVD-Video data rate, so the "DVD-part" of the drive is fast enough, and I'd imagine the player just looks at the directory structure to determine if it's DVD-Video, BD-Video or anything else.
- On the other side, I read everywhere that the BD-Video standard specifies UDF v2.5 as file system. Many players don't care, but for example the Play Station 3 does. Of course, UDF v2.5 could be used for DVDs, too, but if a player checks this, it could also check the media type and refuse to play the movie.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Almost all Bluray players will play a UDF v2.5 with a movie on it, even if the physical media is a DVD.

Something to keep in mind is that you can also encode in 720p, which is still *much* better than DVD resolution, which will let you can cram even more BluRay contents onto a DVD medium.

Another twist is to encode the movie as AVCHD, which was originally meant for HD camcorders recording to DVDs. Many DVD (!) players and all Bluray players are compatible with this format, so if you encode your movie in this format, you have the unexpected benefit that it will work not only in Bluray players but in many DVD players, too.